# How protect spray application from overloading?

Tags: scala, akka, load-balancing, spray

I have the following clear algorithm:

1. Client sends a request to my spray application.
2. Spray receives a request and I see spray receiving load as multiple requests come in.
3. If loading is high, spray returns HTTP 503; otherwise it starts processing the request.

How can I manage current spray loading?

Also, as I understand spray uses akka internally which can be extended with adding additional nodes, so how can I manage the load with additional nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Spray itself uses reactive I/O and can handle very high loads, probably higher than any custom code "protecting" it could handle. So don't worry about trying to protect the spray system itself. If you've got complex processing logic that might take a while to handle certain requests, it might make sense to put a protective throttle around that processing logic, using something like http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2 . And in the case where the queue is full you can simply `complete(StatusCodes.ServiceUnavailable)`.